# Topology question open sets

Tags: general-topology

A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if it is either $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, or an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ where $a$ is any real number.

How do I show that this choice of open sets defines a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What happened when you checked the definition of a topology using this collection of sets? Did any particular axiom cause you trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three axioms that must be met for a collection of subsets to form a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

The first one is that $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$ must be contained in the collection of subsets. Looks like you have that one covered.

---

The second axiom is that given an arbitrary collection of open sets, their union must also be open. Let $\{(a_i,\infty)\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open sets indexed by some set $I$ (note that I may be uncountable for all we know!).

There are two cases to consider:

case 1: The set $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ has no lower bound.

Thus, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists i \in I$ s.t. $n < a_i$, and therefore $\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,\infty) = \mathbb{R}$.

case 2: The set $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ has a lower bound.

In this case, let $\tilde{a} = inf_{i \in I} a_i$.

Then we have $\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,\infty) = (\tilde{a},\infty)$.

---

The third axiom is given any FINITE collection of subsets, their intersection is an open. So, let $\{(a_i,\infty)\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of subsets where the cardinality of $I$ is finite.

Since this collection is finite, let $\tilde{a} = max\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$

Then we can see that $\bigcap_{i \in I} (a_i,\infty) = (\tilde{a},\infty)$.

---

Thus, the three axioms for a collection of subsets to be a topology have been met!!!

Answer (score 2):

Call $\tau\subseteq P(\mathbb{R})$ the collection of sets as you said. Clearly $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset\in \tau$. Now consider an arbitrary union $\bigcup_{T\in I} T$ where each $T\in I$ belongs to $\tau$. If one of the $T$'s is $\mathbb{R}$, this union is $\mathbb{R}$ and thus the union belongs to $\tau$. Of one of the $T$'s is $\emptyset$, we can simply drop them from the union. Hence we may assume that each $T\in I$ is of the form $(a_T,\infty)$.

Note that $\bigcup_{T\in I}(a_T,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ where $a:=\inf_{T\in I}a_T$. This shows that arbitrary unions of things in $\tau$ again belongs to $\tau$.

It remains to show that finite intersection of elements in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$. I'll leave that case to you.

Comment: $(a, \infty) \cap (b, \infty) = (b, \infty)$. The sets mentioned in OP do actually form a topology.

Comment: @MarkKamsma: You are absolutely right, brainfart on my part there. I edited the answer.